# Google Chrome not displaying text

Tags: google-chrome

Yesterday I was installing mods for one game with tool called Vortex (https://www.nexusmods.com/about/vortex/) when suddenly my Google Chrome stopped working properly, most sites I visit don't have any/significant amount of text visible, text is also not visible in Chrome Devtools. I tried restarting my computer and reinstalling Google Chrome browser, without any result. What can be cause of this weird behavior and how can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Questions about desktop software and web browsers, including extensions/add-ons are off-topic. 
 See [what can I ask about here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) This question is better suited to  [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about installable software.